# Flutter Library Footer Issue

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter

Am I utilizing this library correctly? The library is google_nav_bar, but this code returns something that looks like this. As you can see you can't read the footer options - which is a big problem for my app users

```
Container(
        width: size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 54, 54),
            border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(
                //                   <--- right side
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 44, 44, 44),
                width: 3.0,
              ),
            )),
        height: size.height * .06,
        child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  blurRadius: 20,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
                )
              ],
            ),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 8),
                child: GNav(
                  rippleColor: Colors.red,
                  hoverColor: Colors.purple,
                  gap: 8,
                  activeColor: Colors.black,
                  iconSize: 24,
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 12),
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                  tabBackgroundColor: Colors.pink,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  tabs: const [
                    GButton(
                      icon: Icons.stacked_bar_chart,
                      text: 'Statistics',
                    ),
                    GButton(
                      icon: Icons.home,
                      text: 'Home',
                    ),
                    GButton(
                      icon: Icons.fitness_center,
                      text: 'Workout',
                    ),
                    GButton(
                      icon: Icons.settings,
                      text: 'Settings',
                    ),
                  ],
                  selectedIndex: selectedIndex,
                  onTabChange: (index) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )));
```

LOOKS LIKE

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWcf0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the height attribute of the Container.

I mean this one `height: size.height * .06,`. Everything will be fine then.

Good luck.